# Wordpress listing the author of the category

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I list the author of a category?

For example:

```
CAT NAME: INTERNET     AUTHOR: JOHN, DOE, ALEX
CAT NAME: TECH         AUTHOR: JOHN
CAT NAME: CODE         AUTHOR: ALEX
```

Any idea how to do this in Wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the follow code:

```
<?php
$cat_arr = get_categories(); // Get the list of Categories
foreach ($cat_arr as $cat_obj) {
    $term_id = $cat_obj->term_id;

    // Print the Name
    ?>
    <br>
    CAT NAME: <?php echo $cat_obj->name ?>, AUTHOR: 
    <?php
    // Get all Posts of that Category
    $posts = get_posts(array('category'=>$term_id));

    $authors_arr = array();
    foreach ($posts as $post_obj) {
        $author_id = $post_obj->post_author;

            // In depends on where you put this code, the include of the file is required
        if (!function_exists('get_userdata')) {
            include '<your WP folder>/wp-includes/pluggable.php';
        }

        $user_obj = get_userdata($author_id);
            // Only Add the author is isn't already added, to avoid printed twice
        if (!in_array($user_obj->user_login, $authors_arr)) {
            $authors_arr[] = $user_obj->user_login; // Instead of user_login you can use any Database field of the "Users" table
        }
    }
    echo implode(', ', $authors_arr) . '<br>';
}
?>
```

But if you want do this for the "current" Category (not for all Categories) you can use the follow code:

```
    $cat_obj = get_the_category(); // This is what you put in your comment to get Current Category

    $term_id = $cat_obj->term_id;

    // Print the Name
    ?>
    <br>
    CAT NAME: <?php echo $cat_obj->name ?>, AUTHOR: 
    <?php
    // Get all Posts of that Category
    $posts = get_posts(array('category'=>$term_id));

    $authors_arr = array();
    foreach ($posts as $post_obj) {
        $author_id = $post_obj->post_author;

            // In depends on where you put this code, the include of the file is required
        if (!function_exists('get_userdata')) {
            include '<your WP folder>/wp-includes/pluggable.php';
        }

        $user_obj = get_userdata($author_id);
            // Only Add the author is isn't already added, to avoid printed twice
        if (!in_array($user_obj->user_login, $authors_arr)) {
            $authors_arr[] = $user_obj->user_login; // Instead of user_login you can use any Database field of the "Users" table
        }
    }
    echo implode(', ', $authors_arr) . '<br>';
```

Comment: Great works! Many thanks @gsc-leticia

Comment: Would you look at this picture? [link](http://www.screencast.com/t/tb3aQdZY)
How can i do it? I know i don't know very good Php coding.

Comment: Finally, your code is working perfectly, i just need linked author name. How can i do it? i try it with wordpress function but its not worked with your code <?php the_author_link(); ?> can you help me again? :) @gsc-leticia 
Regards

Comment: Hello, you can get the author link with something like this: get_admin_url() . 'user-edit.php?user_id=' . $author_id;

Comment: about http://www.screencast.com/t/tb3aQdZY looking the image I'm not sure what is your need

Comment: Many thanks @gsc-leticia 

Im using this code on my category-sidebar.php and i want list current categories(For Example im viewing Tech category) written author. I think need change this code `$cat_arr = get_categories();
foreach ($cat_arr as $cat_obj) {
    $term_id = $cat_obj->term_id;`

Comment: Depends on the theme and how is getting the Category info. Which theme you use?

Comment: this code getting the category name '$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;' but this is wrong working with your code.

Comment: I update the answer with a second piece of code for this new case you describe. The initial code was for all categories, as you specify in your question, now there is no need of the foreach.